# Need a porcelaine socket for a recessed light fixture

Tags: socket

I just looked at the picture of the recessed light and read all the comments. Well, I need to replace the socket but I do not know what the name is and where to find this porcelain socket...Help please

Comment: Can you link to *which* post you were looking at? This makes very little sense without context.

Comment: Yes, it appears you asked a question, then created a new, second account in order to ask this question.   FYI accounts can be merged.

Comment: Take a photo of the fixture then take that to a hardware or big box store. With "off the wall" or different repairs I have had good luck finding unusual parts at a plumbing & electric specialty store in my town.

Answer (score 1):

Lamp components are *fairly* standardized.  You should be able to go into a *quality* hardware store and get any common part.   If the parts are not common, it may be possible to rearrange it with common parts.

One common problem is people overlamping fixtures; that is, putting too-high-wattage bulbs in fixtures that can't take the heat.  This is a great time to alter the fixture to make that impossible, by changing to a socket type for which high-wattage incandescents are not made.  A good choice for this is a candelabra base, as LED screw-in "bulbs" are widely available at sane price, including some quite high-brightness ones.